# docker build image with tag github sha

Tags: docker, github-actions, docker-tag

Hi I am working in github actions and kubernetes. I am building multiple docker images using matrix as below.

```
- name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: ${{ matrix.docker-image-name }}
          flavor: latest=true
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=branch
            type=ref,event=pr
            type=semver,pattern={{version}}

      - name: Build and push Docker image ${{ matrix.name }}
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: ${{matrix.context }}
          file: ${{ matrix.dockerfile }}
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

This piece of code always build and pushes the image with latest tag. This code is working but i do not want to tag image with latest rather i would like to tag with github sha. So tired something like this

```
tags: ${{ github.sha }}
```

Whenever I add above code my code started failing and throwing the error

> buildx call failed with: ERROR: denied: requested access to the
> resource is denied

I want to push image with sha can someone pls help me to fix this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks